# Importing JS modules from MarkLogic console

Tags: javascript, marklogic, serverside-javascript

**(Forgive me for terminological mistakes, as I am new to JS and MarkLogic, but DO correct me if I am wrong somewhere.)**

I want to import a `BigNumber` object (or is it a class, construct..) from external module `bignumber.js` using MarkLogic qconsole (Server side JS).

This is the suggested way from their github, but it is meant for Node.js and not for SSJS.
https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

```
const BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');
import BigNumber from "bignumber.js";
import { BigNumber } from "bignumber.js";
```

My setup look like this so far:

I have opened HTTP Server

- port: 8111
- root: /
- modules: my-db-modules
- database my-db
- default user: admin

I inserted `bignumber.js` document into `my-db-modules` with the following lines:

```
declareUpdate();
xdmp.documentLoad('path/bignumber.js', {'uri': 'bignumber.js'});
```

I have inserted `bignumber.mjs` file as well.

When I try to import `BigNumber` from `.js` file I get the **'Module bignumber.js not found'**
and if I try importing it from `.mjs` file I get the **'Document is not of executable mimetype. URI: bignumber.mjs'**

I found this section on how to use module db: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/databases#id_38484

But I don't know if I got it right, because I experimented with changing the root of my HTTP Server to `http://marklogic.com/` with no results.

Comment: Try inserting the module with a leading slash `/bignumber.js` or `/bignumber.sjs`. I would expect it to work with a module URI that doesn't start with leading slash, but reproduced your issue and found that it did import and require would work when I used a leading slash, so might be able to work around that resolution issue.

Comment: @MadsHansen wow, it really was that stupid... Huge thanks!

Comment: The culprit with missing leading / is that MarkLogic will always think you are trying to require a relative path, which will most likely fail if you are not calling it from a sibling file..

Comment: Do you two know of any MarkLogic communities? I tried searching gitter, but nothing came up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MadsHansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14419/mads-hansen) pointed out in the comment - document should be inserted with a leading slash in its name.

I just wanted to clarify this next part:

- Importing with `require` works with `.js` files

```
const BigNumber = require('/bignumber.js');
```

- This style of import works with `.mjs` files

```
import BigNumber from "/bignumber.mjs";
import { BigNumber } from "/bignumber.mjs";
```

Both `.js` and `.mjs` files shoud be inserted into modules db, and used in main db.

I loaded files with these lines:

```
xdmp.documentLoad('path/bignumber.js', {'uri': '/bignumber.js'});
xdmp.documentLoad('path/bignumber.mjs', {'uri': '/bignumber.mjs'});
```

Comment: You do not need the path specifically. I assume that Mads was suggesting that because it is clean and easy to troubleshoot and leaves less to be confusedd about.   As an example, you said document load 'path/bignumber.js' that is the IRI.. then you tried to require 'bignumber.js' .. that is not the same IRI as 'path/bignumber.js' and for that it makes perfect sense that the require did  not match.  Yes, you can require based on relative paths, but even then, '/' and 'path' are not the same, so bignumber.js woukd still not have resolved.

Comment: https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.documentLoad here is the definition of xdmp.documentLoad function. First argument is the location from where you load a document. Second argument is optional and it specifies the URI of the document, once it is loaded into the database.

I don't know why it didn't work, but now it works fine. Only thing I changed was the name of of my imported file.

Comment: Good point. Now i am confused. Will try this and be mindful of the additional comments on your original post. Curious

Comment: @DavidEnnis hey, is there an active MarkLogic community?

Comment: The [require function documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/functions#id_60108) explains the rules regarding the path.

Comment: @redCrusaderJr

I would suggest https://www.marklogic.com/community/ this points to resources including developer.marklogic.com

There used to be mailing lists, but those were retiired - i believe in relation to GDPR

Marklogic pages refer to stack overflow. This has the side effect that all questions then must follow the stack overflow guidelines. However, many of the answers are given by seasoned users as well as engineers of the product.

Lastly, i do know that some people use quora.com, but i do not know much about it.

Comment: @DavidEnnis thank you for suggestions :))